# Use background image using css file in ReactJs

Tags: css, reactjs, background

I have a react application in which on checking certain checkboxes I am adding or changing a certain image icon.

```
.checkbox1:checked ~ .icon-span {
   background: url('../../../../assets/images/icon_plus.svg');
}
```

Which is giving me this:

```
background: url([object Module]); //invalid property value
```

But path is correct, how do I correct this?

Comment: How have you configured Webpack do handle `.svg` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work 
`.checkbox1:checked ~ .icon-span {
   background: url(${require("../../../../assets/images/icon_plus.svg")});
}`